# How to deliver large file with Coldfusion 8?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

I am using Coldfusion 8 and I am trying to serve a file of  15mo with cf_content. The problem is that the download freezes randomly. At the moment, I only tried locally, therefore the network is not the problem. I have tried with smaller files and freezes happen less often. I have no idea of the root of the problem. Here is my coldfusion code:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=test.zip">
<cfcontent type="application/zip" file="C:\Test.zip" deletefile="no">
```

I tried to download the file with Chrome, IE and with a piece of java code to download the file (freeze on the read method after some iteration).

Do you have any idea of how I can easily stream a file using Coldfusion? Maybe it is possible using a Java Custom tags but how to write bytes to page as the custom tag write method of the Response object only allows to write a String?

Comment: Did you mean 15MB?  Are you using a shared/hosted environment?  What web server are you using with ColdFusion?

Comment: have you tried putting the file in the webspace and downloading it without cfcontent, just as a test using domain.com/test.zip?

Comment: You can also consider mod_xsendfile if you use Apache

Comment: @Miguel-F I indeed mean 15MG. I am not using a shared/hosted environment and I am using JRun. It is working without any problem when I download directly the file.

Answer (score 4):

I did this for a client.  I am gathering a number of documents and zipping them for download.  Rather than stream them, I save the zip file on the server:

```
<cfzip action="zip" file="#expandpath('/data/briefcase/')##session.order_id#.zip" source="#expandpath('/data/briefcase/')##session.order_id#" overwrite="yes" storepath="no">
```

Then I provide the user a link to download the file.  That way, if it fails, they can always try again.

I then wrote a scheduled task that runs every day and delete any zip files more than 24 hours old.

```
    <cfdirectory action="list" directory="#expandpath('/data/briefcase/')#" name="filelist" >
    <cfquery name="filter_file" dbtype="query" >
    SELECT * from filelist WHERE datelastmodified < #dateadd("h", -48, now())# AND type = 'File'
</cfquery>
    <cfquery name="filter_dir" dbtype="query" >
    SELECT * from filelist WHERE datelastmodified < #dateadd("h", -48, now())# AND type = 'Dir'
</cfquery>
    <cfset path = expandpath('/data/briefcase/')>

    <cfoutput query="filter_file">  
    <cfif fileexists('#directory#/#name#')>
        <cffile action="delete" file="#directory#/#name#" >
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
<cfoutput query="filter_dir">
    <cfif directoryexists('#directory#/#name#')>
        <cfdirectory action="delete" directory="#directory#/#name#" recurse="true" >
    </cfif>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: It could be possible to use this solution, but I would like to stream the file. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

See if helps to prepend your code with:

```
<cfheader name="Content-Length" value="#GetFileInfo('C:\Test.zip').size#">
```

That tells the browser how much data to expect.